# Wpf Tab control DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am using a wpf tab control and i need to detect the tab changes and also be able to change tabs programmatically, i want to do different things in both scenarios..How can i do that?

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
</TabControl>
```

Property in my View Model

```
public ResultObject SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null && SelectedItem.Equals(value)) 
                return;

            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to the `SelectedIndex`;

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
```

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="56,272,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="231" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="507" SelectedIndex="{Binding MyTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

**VB:**

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _MyTabIndex As Integer

Public Property MyTabIndex As Integer
    Get
        Return _MyTabIndex
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)

        If value <> _MyTabIndex Then

            _MyTabIndex = value

            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyTabIndex"))

        End If

    End Set
End Property


Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    MyTabIndex += 1


End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.DataContext = Me


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I tried i run into the same issue that i am facing while trying to use selected item

Comment: I've added some code which works here... Obviously you can only press the button once ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've already bound correctly to SelectedItem. Since that is already available in your model why not change the selected item there when you need to change it. ie:

SelectedItem = MyNewTabToSwitchTo;

Might also need to set the Mode on the binding to twoway.